# Is banking information necessary in order for iAds to start working?

Tags: app-store-connect, iad, contract, banking

Do I have to provide my banking information and agree on the contract(or whatever that is) beforehand, Or should I only do it once it's time to receive the money?( if there is any money at all) and iAds will just start working automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some helpful advice, if you haven't started using iAd yet I wouldn't bother setting up iAd. Apple is [stopping](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a) iAd services, and aren't allowing any more new ads into the network. So at this point if you haven't set up iAd you won't be able to integrate iAd into your app.

Comment: My app is already live!!!! why don't they show that disclaimer in the iAd or the Banking sections?!!! I guess I will start integrating AdMob then.

Comment: @Abdou023 Ya, it is strange how they didn't put a notice on those sections. Apple didn't do the best job notifying us about the iAd situation...

Comment: Not exactly `The announcement is confusingly worded, but it does not mean that all of iAd is being discontinued. Developers will still be able to show iAd banners in their application; it’s just that the inventory for App Store apps to advertise will no longer exist. This is a blessing and a curse — it won’t help iAd improve its fill-rates but the CPM on these type of ads was significantly lower as the buy-in from the publisher side was also lower.` from here http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/15/apple-will-discontinue-iad-app-network-for-developers-on-june-30th/

Comment: @Lanorkin But look I emailed the iAd team and they replied:  Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, effective January 15th, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue, if you were previously accepted into the network, until June 30. Any apps submitted to iAd after January 15th will not be accepted into the platform.